# Reading and Writing Excel files in .NET WPF

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, interop, oledb

I am at a crossroads here and I need input from some people with experience with this. I want to be able to read and write from Excel for my WPF application (C#), but the options that I am seeing online are either clunky and messy (Interop) or won't work on a x64 bit application (OleDb). Are there other options for me to look at? Thanks

edit: here are my connection strings for OleDB

```
        if (Path.GetExtension(filePath) == ".xls")
        {
            connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                   Data Source = '" + filePath + 
                   "';Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";
        }
        else if(Path.GetExtension(filePath) == ".xlsx")
        {
            connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                  Data Source='" + filePath +
                  "';Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\"";
        }
```

Comment: here is the exception that I am getting in OleDB: 
  Message=The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. \n I've installed AccessDatabaseEngine_x64 on my machine (2010). is there something that i need to do to get the connection to point to this installation. Is anything i'm saying making sense?

Comment: Check out [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started).  It's available as a NuGet package.

Comment: from what i'm reading it uses xlsx. Is there a solution for xls as well?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the options are for .xls

Comment: EPPlus does not support xls. If I recall correctly, the ACE provider has to match the bitness of the Office installation. If at all possible, I would go with EPPlus. Note that EPPlus has gone commercial as of the latest version, but previous versions are still free.

Comment: If you need .xls, that means that your must have Excel versions lower than 2007 (so 2003 or lower) installed. That is pretty old!

Comment: If you want to go hardcore (but again only xlsx), you can use Open XML: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/ That will give you the power of EPPlus minus the user-friendliness. It is like the bare-bones version of building an Office document from scratch. If you do not have complex requirements, it may be worth playing with. I did it not too long ago and while EPPlus is very, very much  easier, I got it to work, so it isn't rocket science. Just tedious and verbose.

Comment: i might just give up on xls. I'll try epp first and see how it performs. openxml would be a good back up. thanks for the info guys.

Comment: +1 for EPPlus if you don't need .xls. For .xls — I had some positive experience using [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi).